# Construir un dataframe de pandas con cada columna igual a la media de las columnas de varios dataframes de pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Tengo 21 data frames de pandas, todos ellos lucen de la siguiente forma:

```
|country |   reference   | price_1|price_2 |price 3| price_4 |
|------------------------------------------------------------
|A       |1              | 0      |   5    | 13    | 4       |
|A       |2              | 3      |   8    | 4     | 5       |
|A       |3              | 0      |   4    | 6     | 9       |
|A       |4              | 1      |  12    | 11    | 12      |  
|A       |5              |45      |   9    | 3     | 13      |
|A       |6              |3       |   6    | 5     | 16      |
|A       |7              |34      |   7    | 2     | 17      |
```

Aqui, uso A como el nombre del país y el dataframe se llama `dataA`, por ejemplo el segundo dataframe, para el país B luce de la siguiente forma (su nombre es `dataB`):

```
|country |   reference   | price_1|price_2 |price 3| price_4|
|------------------------------------------------------------
|B       |1              | 0      |   15   | 0    | 1       |
|B       |2              | 4      |   0    | 0    | 2       |
|B       |3              | 0      |   1    | 1    | 0       |
|B       |4              | 5      |  2     | 1    | 1       |  
|B       |5              |4       |   3    | 2    | 1       |
|B       |6              |6       |   4    | 0    | 1       |
|B       |7              |3       |   8    | 2    | 0       |
```

y los data frame tienen nombres como A.xlsx, B.xlsx (dependiendo del nombre del país) en mi carpeta.  Necesito tener la media de cada columna  `price_1, price_2 and price_3,` e hice esto:

```
datosA1 = dataA.iloc[:,2:5]
A_mean_loss = dataA1.mean(axis=0)
```

Entonces, obtengo el  dataframe A_mean_loss:

```
|price_1|12.28|
|price_2|7.3  |
|price_3|6.29 |
|price_4|10.85|
```

Lo que necesito es hacer lo mismo, de manera eficiente para los 21 dataframes de panda y obtener un nuevo dataframe que luzca así

What I need is to do the same in a efficiently way for the 21 panda dataframes and to get a new dataframe that looks like this:

```
|price id| A   |B   |C   |D   |E   |.......|(Country21)|
---------------------------------------------------------
|1       |12.28|3.14|x   |x   |x   |.......|x          |
|2       |7.3  |4.71|x   |x   |x   |.......|x          |          
|3       |6.29 |0.86|x   |x   |x   |.......|x          |
|4       |10.85|0.86|x   |x   |x   |.......|x          |
```

Soy realmente nueva en Python y programando en general, pero creo que esto puede ser resulto generalizando lo que hice con una función con loop for sobre la lista de data frames `data_countries=[dataA,dataB,dataC,dataD,...,dataU]`

Agradecería muchísimo cualquier ayuda!

Posdata: Estoy trabajando en Atom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza cualquier lógica que quieras y te sientas cómoda para leer todos los excels con pandas y agrúpalos en una lista. Por ejemplo puedes hacer algo así:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_files = [
    'A.xlsx',
    'B.xlsx',
    'C.xlsx',
    # ...
]

dfs = []

for file in excel_files:
    dfs.append(pd.read_excel(file))
```

Usa ahora `pandas.concat()` para concatenar los dataframes en uno:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

esto te generará un dataframe de este tipo:

| country | reference | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | price_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 55 | 10 | 98 | 53 | 88 |
| A | 88 | 36 | 33 | 6 | 42 |
| A | 97 | 8 | 48 | 76 | 56 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| B | 37 | 38 | 29 | 31 | 59 |
| B | 74 | 47 | 61 | 17 | 21 |
| B | 33 | 94 | 40 | 79 | 10 |
| B | 72 | 60 | 66 | 25 | 43 |
| B | 31 | 50 | 77 | 18 | 40 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| C | 71 | 19 | 24 | 63 | 34 |
| C | 64 | 84 | 16 | 49 | 59 |
| C | 18 | 4 | 51 | 10 | 93 |
| C | 7 | 61 | 7 | 64 | 41 |
| C | 70 | 26 | 43 | 61 | 85 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Agrupa ese dataframe con `groupby()` por la columna country utilizando `mean()` como función de agregación descartando la columna referencia:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['reference']).groupby('country').mean()
```

Tu dataframe ahora mismo será algo así:

| country | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | price_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5.34 | 67.33 | 86.1 | 22.8 |
| B | 12.4 | 20.2 | 55.5 | 35.9 |
| C | 45.1 | 3.13 | 1.30 | 77.9 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Sólo tienes que transponerlo con `.T` y reiniciar el índice con `reset_index()`

```
df = df.T.reset_index()
```

| index | A | B | C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| price_1 | 5.34 | 12.4 | 45.1 | ... |
| price_2 | 67.33 | 20.2 | 3.13 | ... |
| price_3 | 86.1 | 55.5 | 1.30 | ... |
| price_4 | 22.8 | 35.9 | 77.9 | ... |

Finalmente, utiliza la columna index para construir la columna `price id`:

```
df.rename(columns={'index': 'price id'}, inplace=True)
df['price id'] = df['price id'].apply(lambda x: int(x.replace('price_', '')))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! pude lograrlo